# Choices disappear when adding class to Select

Tags: django-forms

I have a model

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    foobar_choice = models.CharField(choices=FOOBAR_CHOICES, default='option_a', blank=False, null=False)
```

and a ModelForm

```
class FooBarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ['foobar_choice']
```

And this works. When I load the form into my template it shows all the values I defined in FOOBAR_CHOICES.

What I want is to add a class to the widget of the field foobar_choice. I have tried to do this by adding the following code to FooBarForm,

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FooBarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['foobar_choice'].widget = Select(attrs={
        'class': 'myClass',
        })
```

When I do this my template return an empty *Select* object, albeit with the correct class. What is going on here? Am I using the wrong widget or am I somehow overwritting something by changing the attrs dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear some of the django magic gets overwritten when you manually define a widget. I managed to fix my problem by changing the init bit to

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FooBarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['foobar_choice'].widget = Select(attrs={
        'class': 'myClass',
        },
    choices=FOOBAR_CHOICES)
```